# Zoomming into an image with ImageMagick

Tags: image, imagemagick

I would like to zoom into an image `test.png`. That is, as a silly example, I would like to go from this

[image]

to this

[image]

The only way I was able to do it was with

```
convert -resize 110% test.png -gravity Center \
        -crop 800x600+0+0 +repage 1.png
```

This is re-scaling the picture and then cropping it to its original size. The problem is that this only works because I already know that the original size of the image is 800x600.

How can I make this work without knowing the size of the image beforehand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this, apparently, is with the `-distort` option:

```
convert -distort SRT '1.1 0' +repage test.png 2.png
```

where `1.1` is a 110% zoom and the `0` is a rotation angle.